# лучший способ получения мини-изображения (Thumbnail) у картинки

Tags: java, android, изображения, thumbnails

Имеется картинка, размещенная на карте памяти телефона, при загрузке приложения нужно выводить ее мини-превью (thumbnail), делаю таким способом:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path,
                                              int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // Читаем с inJustDecodeBounds=true для определения размеров
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Вычисляем inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Читаем с использованием inSampleSize коэффициента
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                 int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Реальные размеры изображения
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Вычисляем наибольший inSampleSize, который будет кратным двум
        // и оставит полученные размеры больше, чем требуемые
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

но данный способ не очень хорош по времени :(
Покопавшись, нашел вот этот:

```
private Bitmap getThumbnail(String path) {
    final int THUMBSIZE = 128;

    return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path),
            THUMBSIZE,
            THUMBSIZE);
}
```

но качество картинки оставляет желать лучшего,
может быть есть какой-то другой способ, чтобы и по времени было быстро и качество картинки было оптимальное.
p.s. думал о сохранении thumbnail на карту памяти и уже ее подгружать

Comment: так сделайте THUMBSIZE = 300 например, а лучше в dp задать этот размер, у вас же слишком маленькое превью, вот и качество такое

Comment: да, действительно, я забыл, что размер передается в px, переконвертировал из dp в px и все стало нормально, спасибо:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была, в том, что в данном методе:

```
private Bitmap getThumbnail(String path) {
final int THUMBSIZE = 128;

return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path),
        THUMBSIZE,
        THUMBSIZE);
}
```

значения указываются в пикселях, а не в dp, поэтому я просто переконвертировал размер, который должен быть из dp -> px:

```
private Bitmap getThumbnail(String path) {
    final int THUMBSIZEINDP = 128;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path),
            (int) (THUMBSIZEINDP * displayMetrics.density),
            (int) (THUMBSIZEINDP * displayMetrics.density));
}
```

и качество стало the best :)